# force corona sdk to render in a loop

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Inside a loop I change the text of a textfield. But corona does not render until the loop is finished. Is it possible to force a render inside a loop?

I have tried with display.setDrawMode( "forceRender" ) and to do a sleep in the loop but it does not matter. Im trying to do a progressbar that updates.

Comment: Instead of using a loop consider using something like "local progressTimer = timer.performWithDelay( 1000, updateProgress, -1 )" and having the updateProgress function take care of updating the progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corona only renders between your event handlers. While your handler loops, Corona cannot update the display. Basically all commands in your handler than affect the display take effect only after the handler returns control to Corona. So if you want to show a value change repeatedly in a text field, you can't use a loop, only last change to the value will be visible on display, and only after return.

Therefore, you need to use one of Corona's mechanisms to cause the update to occur again. For example, you could listen for `Runtime`'s `enterFrame` event; in there, determine if it is time to update the value and/or the text field and act accordingly. If this leads to too many updates (it will be 30 or 60 times per second), then another way would be to schedule an update of text field for later, as suggested by Frozire:

```
function updateValueDisplayed()
    ...compute new value...
    ...if changed, update the display object that shows the value...
end

timer.performWithDelay( 500, updateValueDisplayed, -1 )
```

The above will call `updateValueDisplayed` twice per second, until you exit. If the delay should be different every time, or should stop under certain conditions, then you could `performWithDelay` only once (remove third call parameter) and call `timer.performWithDelay( delay, updateValueDisplayed)` from within `updateValueDisplayed` as appropriate.

Clarification: you can't use a `for` loop. You can only use a repeated function call, two ways are described above.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have tried both of them but neither of them work. Then enterframe function updates but as soon as the loop starts the update function holds and starts updating directly after the loop is finished. Its like corona only uses one thread.

Comment: Yes, Corona only runs on one "thread". You aren't ment to create a new loop to continously handle the update inside the updateValueDisplayed() function. Instead the updateValueDisplayed() function becomes your loop, this function is continously called. So you take the logic inside your loop and put it into this function.